# How to define alias for non interactive/non login shell?

Tags: bash, alias

I have a user (zabbix) with shell set to `/sbin/nologin`. The user's home is `/var/lib/zabbix` and I inserted `alias curl='curl -k'` into `~zabbix/.bashrc`. However it does not work when I (for testing purpose) issue
`sudo -u zabbix curl https://HOST-WITH-INVALID-ISSUER-CERTIFICATE`, it returns null.

Actually, the command `curl https://HOST-WITH-INVALID-ISSUER-CERTIFICATE` will execute remotely via zabbix-server <--> zabbix-agent interaction.

Comment: Use a function instead, maybe.

Comment: you could create a script `/usr/local/bin/curl` that does just `/usr/bin/curl -k ...` and make sure `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your path. But you'll have to remember to call `/usr/bin/curl` instead of just `curl` for all your other users so that may not be option for you.

Comment: @muru where would you write this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of an alias, use a `.curlrc` file in `~zabbix`. This contains command line arguments to be added to the `curl` command when it is run.

```
# --insecure being the more readable synonym for -k
$ echo "insecure" >> ~zabbix/.curlrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Non-interactive shells do not expand aliases by default. You need to execute `shopt -s expand_aliases` explicitly before defining the aliases. Be aware that `~/.bashrc` is generally only sourced with an interactive shell as well, so you might want to explicitly source it.

All that being said, functions are a good alternative to aliases, and they do not need any semi-obscure setup to get working. It would look like this:

```
curl() { command curl -k "$@"; }
```

The `command` builtin searches `$PATH` for the command, so you will not go down the recursion rabbit hole. You can define it in a file that is sourced when the shell is initialized.

Comment: A function doesn't help here. If there's a place to define a function, it also allows defining aliases.

Comment: I think Gilles is right. Where should I define that function in order to be accessible by Non-interactive shells?